# Is it possible to run lxc based containers inside a docker based parent container?

Tags: docker, lxc

I have an existing lxc based container building framework that I'd like to host inside of a docker based container.  I've seen references to nesting lxc based containers, but I've seen nothing about nesting them with a docker based parent.

First problem I run into when I try it is lxbr0 is missing in the docker parent. Not sure how to resolve that or if that's the only problem I'll run into.

Is this possible?

Here are the details of what I've tried.

```
On a Ubuntu 14.04 system
@ubuntu ~ $ docker version
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a

@ubuntu ~ $ docker run -i -t --privileged ubuntu:14.04 bash
root@d3e60c05b4f3:/# apt-get update
...
apt-get install lxc
...

root@d3e60c05b4f3:/# lxc-create -n t0 -t download -B dir -- -d centos -r 6 -a amd64
Setting up the GPG keyring
Downloading the image index
Downloading the rootfs
Downloading the metadata
The image cache is now ready
Unpacking the rootfs

---
You just created a CentOS container (release=6, arch=amd64, variant=default)
The default root password is: root

root@d3e60c05b4f3:/# lxc-start -n t0
lxc-start: failed to attach 'veth3EUUJS' to the bridge 'lxcbr0' : No such device
lxc-start: failed to create netdev
lxc-start: failed to create the network
lxc-start: failed to spawn 't0'
lxc-start: The container failed to start.
lxc-start: Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
root@d3e60c05b4f3:/# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:48:86:e5:6d:a7  
          inet addr:172.17.0.3  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c48:86ff:fee5:6da7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:50764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:95008668 (95.0 MB)  TX bytes:1528822 (1.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

root@d3e60c05b4f3:/#
```

Comment: Can you share code of what you have tried?

Comment: Ordinarily the bridge is made as part of the LXC installation - I wonder why it's failed to do so here?

Comment: you could try image which used to run docker in docker - https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/